# Upload files to user's drive account app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

is it possible to create an app in Google App Script that allows users to sign in with their google account and send a file to their own google drive account?
I found a lot of examples where other users can send files to my drive account, but that is not what I am looking for.
Many thanks.

Comment: About `I found a lot of examples where other users can send files to my drive account, but that is not what I am looking for.`, can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google Drive Picker**

What you could be looking at is Google Picker, it would allow you to create a "file open" dialog similar to this:

[image]

You can review the code sample over this official documentation on how to create it and add it to App Script:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

This would open the possibility to build and use the Drive Picker API so users can select where they like to upload the file.

You can review the examples from here, and one of this mentions a function that would allow the user to pick the folder where it would be uploading the specific file:

- https://gist.github.com/fernandovega/5598b242bb30eeb6fb9ae1239f0b2961

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview